# selenium find class name

Tags: selenium, webdriver

In my web page is a list of items,each item consists of image and text.Its like a menu of items.

I need to check if a particular item exists in the list. I want to do this based on checking if an image exists

The html looks like:

```
<li class="jekyllListElement font_01" id="baseScreen_GUI_LI_0" style="top: 0px; width: 665px; height: 118px; background-color: transparent; background-image: none;">
  <div class="jekyllTableBlock font_01">
    <div class="jekyllTableBlockItemPicture" style="width: 102px;">
      <img class="**jekyllTableBlockItemPicture mainmenu_localsearch**" src="/static/img/img_gold/mainmenu/localsearchnew.png" width="102">
    </div>
    <div class="jekyllTableBlockText">
      <div>
        <div class="jekyllTableBlockItemText" style="width: 501px;">
          Local Search 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="jekyllTableBlockItemIcon mainmenu_undefined">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

For example I want to check if image class **jekyllTableBlockItemPicture mainmenu_localsearch** exists

How can this be achieved?
Please help

Comment: do you mean image present or not in web page?

Comment: please try to improve your question, show us parts of the html please

Answer (score 0):

You mean , you want to verify DOM object using class name attribute. Am I right ? If so,

Below logic would help you

```
isElementPresent(driver,By.xpath("//img[@class='urclassname']")); 
isElementPresent(driver,By.xpath("//img[contains(@class,'some_part_of_urclassname')]"));

or

isElementPresent(driver,By.cssSelector("img[class='urclassname']"));
isElementPresent(driver,By.cssSelector("img[class*='some_part_of_urclassname']"));
```

For [isElementPresent implementation see this link](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2012/07/iselementpresent.html).